# PHP login and register error

Tags: php

The error shown is

> "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on string in D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php:22 Stack trace: #0 D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\login.php(19): ManageUsers->LoginUsers('kayzmark', 'ultimate') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php on line 22"

```
<?php
class ManageUsers{
    public $link;

    function __construct(){
        $db_connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }

    function registerUsers($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO users (password,ip_address,date,time,username, email, uname) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array ($password, $ip_address, $date, $time, $username, $email, $uname);
        $query->execute($values);
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }

    function LoginUsers($username, $password){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        return $rowCount;
    }

    function GetUserInfo($username){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
        $rowCount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowCount ==1)
        {
            $result = $query->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }
        else
        {
            return $rowCount;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @KayzMark, welcome to StackOverflow. Please make sure to include a clear __problem statement__ as to what exactly you need help with when posting a question in the future. Make sure you review the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for help with things like [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) for future reference. The error message you supply is pretty straight-forward. You called a method on something that is a `String` and not an `Object` on _line 22_ of that file.

Answer (score 0):

You are probaly calling `->query()` on a string instead of the object. Could you verify that the variable where you call query() on contains the right object and you are not overriding it by mistake?

Comment: By mistake $this-->link = 'abc' and later in code $this-->link-->query()

Comment: Hi @Bolivir, this answer should really be a comment since further discussion is required to understand the question. Please remember that StackOverflow is not a place to get debugging help. Make sure to review [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center as well, for future reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@Bolivir is right: the error you getting is because `$this-link` is a string, rather than an object.

Could it be that `$this->link = $db_connection->connect();` can also return a string instead of a connection (for example, when you enter wrong  credentials or when the database is down)?

Or shouldn't `$this->link` be a reference to `$db_connection`? Just trying stuff out here, since I don't know what DB wrapper you are using.

What does the `dbConnection::connect()`-method look like?

Comment: `public function connect(){
   try{
    $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->db_host;dbname=$this->db_name",$this->db_user,$this->db_pass);
    return $this->db_conn;
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
    return $e->getMessage();
   }
  }`

Comment: Looking at your function my guess is that you don't get a `PDO` object back, but the error message `$e->getMessage()`. Read your message(`echo $this->link` in your case) and you know what's wrong. But better design would be if your `dbConnection` class throws an error  and your `ManageUsers` class catches it.

Comment: so this is better right `public function dbConnection()
 {

     $this->conn = null;
        try
  {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
   $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }
  catch(PDOException $exception)
  {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }`

Comment: No, don't catch the exception in your database class, but catch it in the class that uses your database class. But this is programming logic and beyond the scope of your question. What is on-topic: can you share with us what the error message is?

Comment: Connection Error: could not find driver
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php:22 Stack trace: #0 D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\login.php(19): ManageUsers->LoginUsers('anuraj', '123') #1 {main} thrown in D:\Users\kukor\Documents\XAMPP\htdocs\timetable\class.ManageUsers.php on line 22